# Is It Worth It Working Out Every Practice Problem In Math? (Without a calculator)

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I'm bouncing back between trig, algebra, and calc books. I've noticed that most of the problems at some point seem to distill into very tedious arithmetic. It is nice to have the prowess of calculating things by hand, but it is taking a while to finish each problem. Could I be spending my time more efficiently using a calculator to complete many more problems instead?

Comment: Getting the right answer is *never* the point of doing a problem.  The problem is to learn by doing.  Use the calculator for the arithmetic you know.  Do not use a calculator for the parts that you struggle with.

Comment: If you understand how to perform the calculations then, yes, after a while you start seeing things ahead of time. I minimalize arithmetics as much as I can, but I try not to do any sloppy argumentation.